# Change start -> run -> chrome to include switches

Tags: windows, registry

I've looked around the internet for a way to use Windows's Windows+R shortcut to run chrome (or any app) with with default command-line switches.

My wife and I share a Windows User, but in Chrome, we have separate users so we don't have to share settings, bookmarks, etc.

Chrome has a switch `--profile-directory="[someDir]"` that will allow you to set the user when it's run.  I'm the only one who uses the Windows+R shortcut, so I'd like to set the default setting, when I type "chrome", to run a chrome instance with my user, regardless of the last chrome window opened (which is how it decides which user to run).

It looks like the right place to make this change is in the registry:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe`

If I edit the (Default) key to include `--profile-directory="Default"`, Windows can't find the path, presumably because it puts quotes around the whole thing when I press enter on the Run dialog box.

Using something akin to SQL Injection and adding strategically placed quotes doesn't work either--my guess is that it escapes them.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#appPaths) hints that you might be able to add command-line parameters as subkeys to the `...\App Paths\chrome.exe` key, but I tried adding `--profile-directory` = `"Default"`, `--profile-directory=` = `"Default"`, and `--profile-directory="Default"` = (empty string), none of which worked.

Anyone know how to do this, or are perhaps better at Google than I am?

As a last resort, I can replace the `(Default)` reg key to point to a batch file that runs chrome.exe with the switch, but I would really rather not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to use the *internal* Chrome profile name.

I'm running ChromePortable, so the first thing I had to do was change the user-data-dir

chrome://version helps confirm the profile in use....

At first I thought a full path was required. Actually, it's just the internal name that's referenced...

Here's an example of my revised Chrome shortcut

L:\OS\MyApps\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=L:\OS\MyApps\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile --profile-directory="Profile 1"

(as always, re command args, any spaces should be surrounded by quotes)